# python-3.5, timestamp to YYYYmmDDHHMMSS

Tags: timestamp, python-3.5

Hello to every saturday workers!
I need to convert a timestamp to YYYYmmDDHHMMSS. The following works well

```
    timestamp=now_var[27:38]                      # timestamp string 
dth_now=(                               # string date heure 
    datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
        int(timestamp)
     ).strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
)                                       # a string
```

but gives an alert

```
  File "C:\_Python\kWh_compare.py", line 35, in <module>
).strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Where is the problem ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the API, but could it be "fromtimestamp" needs a string instead of an int?

Otherwise try splitting it in its several operations

```
timestamp=now_var[27:38] 
inttimestamp=int(timestamp)
datetimestamp=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(inttimestamp)
dth_now=datetimestamp.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `now_var[27:38] == ''`
You can see this from the string that ValueError reports.

Reproduce like this: `int('')`

How to fix depends on what you are trying to achieve, one way could be `timestamp='0'+now_var[27:38]`